# plistlib can't read Safari's plist file

Tags: python, plist

I'm trying to modify a plist file using python. I copied a plist from my library to my desktop to safely play with it. I've imported `os` and `plistlib`. I'm following what I see in the [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/plistlib.html).

```
import plistlib
import os

test_prefs = "~/Desktop/com.apple.Safari.plist"

x = readPlist(os.path.expanduser(test_prefs))
print x["TopSitesGridArrangement"]
```

But this fails. What am I doing wrong?

The exact error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Josh/Desktop/destroy.py", line 11, in <module>
    x = readPlist(os.path.expanduser(test_prefs))
NameError: name 'readPlist' is not defined
```

When I change it to `x = plistlib.readPlist(os.path.expanduser(test_prefs))` the errors I get are as follows (my file name is called destroy.py):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Josh/Desktop/destroy.py", line 11, in <module>
    x = plistlib.readPlist(os.path.expanduser(test_prefs))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 78, in readPlist
    rootObject = p.parse(pathOrFile)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plistlib.py", line 406, in parse
    parser.ParseFile(fileobj)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 8
```

Comment: This shouldn't give the error you're reporting. Can you [edit] your question to include the **full traceback**?

Comment: Instead of `x = readPlist(...` have you tried `x = plistlib.readPlist(...`?

Comment: @mhlester you are correct. I've updated it with the true error message.

Comment: @fredtantini yes I did try that before, I get 3 errors when I do that.

Comment: @wetjosh: well that is the reason you're getting this `NameError`. change it to `plistlib.readPlist` and then show us what that error is

Comment: @Claudiu 1 error doesn't have an explanation but references the line you told me to change. Another doesn't have an explanation but references line 78 of plistlib.py. And the third references line 406 of plislib.py and says: xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 8

Comment: @wetjosh: those are all the same error. it's just telling you where it came from. Your issue might be that the `.plist` file you are presenting is not well-formed. Could you upload it somewhere so we could test it? EDIT: Interesting, my Safari's plist also doesn't work. There is something afoot here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that Safari's plist file is actually a binary plist file format, which the built-in `plistlib` can't read. However, [biplist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/biplist) can read these files (requires installation):

```
>>> import biplist
>>> x = biplist.readPlist("com.apple.Safari.plist")
>>> x['LastOSVersionSafariWasLaunchedOn']
'10.9.1'
```

Alternatively, you can use [`plutil`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/plutil.1.html) to first convert the binary plist format to xml format, and then read it using `plistlib`:

```
$ plutil -convert xml1 com.apple.Safari.plist
$ python
>>> import plistlib
>>> x = plistlib.readPlist("com.apple.Safari.plist")
>>> x['LastOSVersionSafariWasLaunchedOn']
'10.9.1'
```

Comment: there we go. I used the biplist option. Works as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `x = plistlib.readPlist(os.path.expanduser(test_prefs))`?

Comment: please see above comment to @Claudiu

Comment: It did answer the question at the time, but the question has since been revised.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
import plistlib
```

Creates a namespace `plistlib`, in which all its objects are stored, in order to keep from clobbering your own variable names.

To access the function `readPlist`, you need to use the dot-notation to access `plistlib.readPlist`:

```
x = plistlib.readPlist(os.path.expanduser(test_prefs))
```

---

As an alternative, you can use this syntax to bring what you need into your global space:

```
from plistlib import readPlist, writePlist  # and anything else...
```

Comment: please see above comment to @Claudiu

Comment: You'll need to edit your question with the **full traceback** of the errors you receive

Comment: Looks like it's an invalid plist file

Comment: whaaaat. It's valid enough for Safari. I didn't do anything to it. Created by the OS. No modifications.